# Using PHP to find directory names

Tags: php, wordpress

I dont know how to go into this without going well overboard with the description so Ill try to be as short hand as I can without leaving out the important bits. I previously looked at a command line solution for this but couldn't find one. So thinking about a PHP solution instead.

I currently have a tonne of images all saved into various folders in the following layout:

```
locationname/hotelname/image.jpg
locationname/businessname/hotelname/image.jpg
locationname/businessname/hotelname/image.jpg
locationname/operatorname/hotelname/image.jpg
```

Obviously the common denominator here is that the directories always end with the hotel name, luckily the hotel name is the same name as the Wordpress Post Title that the images relate to.

Rather than try to rearrange all the $hotelname folders up into the same directory, am I right in thinking I can scan the directories for the lowest dir from where I can then source the images from. A bit like a foreach loop with image sourced like:

```
<img src="$calculatedurl/image.jpg"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: What I want to achieve.

Each Post has a post title and the title is pretty much 100% the same name as the folder in the uploads directory that contains its images. So, for the hotel called "Agrade Apartments", the images are stored in:

```
wp-content/uploads/locationame/Agrade Apartments/image.jpg
```

There are well over 1000 apartments, so rather than try to go through each post and add the images manually, I want to write a conditional statement that will check to see if the image has attachments, if it does then show the images attached, if it doesnt, then get the $posttitle and scan the uploads directories for a folder with the same name, get the contents and foreach $contents as $content add the file to the jQuery slider.

So i roughly end up with:

```
 $posttitle = the_title();

 $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'attachment',
 'numberposts' => -1,
 'post_status' => null,
 'post_parent' => $post->ID
 );

 $attachments = get_posts( $args );
 $alternativeurl = 
  if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
       echo '<li>';
       echo wp_get_attachment_image_src();
       echo '</li>';
      }
  } else {
  //use a php function to loop through all the folders in the 
  //wp-content/uploads that match the $posttitle variable.
  //when found, loop through each file inside the folder and add 
  //each url to my jQuery slider as a foreach loop.
  }
```

Hope that helps explain a little further.

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: Rather than try to rearrange all the $hotelname folders up into the same directory, am I right in thinking I can scan the directories for the lowest dir from where I can then source the images from. A bit like a foreach loop with image sourced like:

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @AlexKnopp tip: If someone asks a question in comments and you think that info is already in the question - it's not, and copying and pasting a bit of the question into a comment _is not helpful_.

Comment: Implement it with a recursive function which will go through all folders/subfolders/etc until you find the jpg. Google for previous php examples on how to do a folder search with a recursive function. .

Comment: Thats why im here. Google wasnt to helpful. Neither is telling me to go look somewhere else to be honest. Thanks though.

Comment: You would be better off storing the images in folders numbered for the relevant record ID. That would make it quick and easy to locate the files, and also protect you against the possibility of a name being changed.

Comment: There is still no question in your "question". But at least there is more information now and we can assume the comment from the code is your question. PHP can help you with function [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). Also [`readdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) and the related functions or the [`Dir` class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php) (the OOP version of `readdir()`).

Comment: @AlexKnopp: I was merely pointing out HOW you can achieve what you desire by constructing a recursive function which can be used to iterate folder and subfolders to look for .jpg files. Its common practice and just a word of advice how i would achieve than one part of your problem of gathering jpgs from you folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand, you like to scan all folder hierarchy and find all images which "belong" to some list of hotels.

if we suppose what all hotel names are unique and you have access to the file system where the images are, i would recommend you

1. use `readdir()` to get contents of the root directory where the images stored
2. use `id_dir()` and `is_file()` to check if the next item is a directory or a regular file
3. iterate deeper to hierarchy
4. if a file comply with your requirements (e.g. it's "*.jpg") you can get full path of it's directory using `realpath()` and split the string using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` as delimiter
5. `array_pop()` will give you the name which is hotel name

here is some additional info:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php

Answer (score 0):

I have something like that to show all the folders

```
$sName = '.';
$oDir    = opendir($sName);
$aDirList = array();

while($sDir = readdir($oDir)) {
    if($sDir != '.' && $sDir != '..') {
        if(is_dir($sName.'/'.$sDir)) {
            $aDirList[] = $sDir;
        }
    }
}

closedir($oDir);

if(!empty($aDirList)) {
    sort($aDirList);
    echo "Folders list : <br>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($aDirList as $sDir) {
        echo "<li><a href=\"$sName/$sDir \">$sDir</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Maybe they you gonna have some errors but it's an example of my code ...

Hope I help you ! :)

Comment: Ive changed the first line to read $sName = get_site_url().'/wp-content/uploads';
Im using your example but im getting errors:
http://greenmonkeypublicrelations.com/citypads/functions/

Comment: Oh ... This little code is totally functional for me. Learn the PHP doc to find with you are getting this errors. I'll take a look when I have a little bit of time to help you. Good luck !